# How can I change the default width of VS Code's editor find widget?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to make the search field in a document larger by default in VS Code? So that the size remains the same the next time you start the program!

[Simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQTKO.jpg)

Comment: Left of the small arrow/caret symbol allowing you to extend "search" into "search and replace" is a thick border line. Use the mouse to drag this line to the left to extend the width of the search input. Using VS Code 1.83.1 in fullscreen mode on macOS I am able to extend the search input over the complete length of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this doesn't seem to be supported. I also checked VS Code Insiders 1.84 and it's not in there either.

As for changing the *default* size, I think this is covered by [Search bar input field very narrow #33349](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33349). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it and increase its prioritization. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. But please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump" (just give it a thumbs up if that's what you want to convey).

As for getting VS Code to remember the size of the find widget across reloads or closing and reopening a workspace, I don't see an existing issue ticket covering this in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+label%3Aeditor-find+label%3Aunder-discussion or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+label%3Aeditor-find+label%3Afeature-request or from from the first page of search results from googling "`github vscode issues remember size of find widget`". I suggest that you raise an issue ticket. I think there are some interesting design questions here that you'll probably want to bring up in your issue ticket- particularly at what level the remembering is done (globally? per workspace? per file in workspace?)

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.